# Applications of monotonic functions in Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, soft-question, monotone-functions

Is there some result in Analysis saying that all functions of a particular kind can be constructed from monotonic functions? What's that class of functions that could be constructed? How to construct them from monotonic functions (ie. what operations are needed? Adding functions? Multiplying functions? etc.)

Comment: The set of functions which, on a compact interval, can be written as the difference of (bounded) monotone functions is the set of functions with bounded variation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation

Comment: There is an equivalence between radial positive semi-definite functions and completely monotone profiles: http://www.math.iit.edu/~fass/603_ch2.pdf